# PNG has black background

Tags: php, image-processing, png

I'm using a lib to easy save images.

http://www.white-hat-web-design.co.uk/blog/resizing-images-with-php/

But the problem is that it saves transparant png with black background. I have search and found something that should work but is not working for me.

[imagecolortransparent()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.imagecolortransparent.php) should normally do it.
But for me I still see the black background.

What I'm I doing wrong?

```
$imagename = $_FILES['file']['name'];           
$target = "source/images/".$imagename;
$image->save($target);


function save($filename, $image_type=IMAGETYPE_JPEG, $compression=75, $permissions=null){

  if( $image_type == IMAGETYPE_PNG ){

      $image = $this->image;

      $black = imagecolorallocate($image, 0, 0, 0);
      imagecolortransparent($image, $black);

      imagepng($image,$filename);
  }
```

}

Comment: Are you using a PNG or a JPG image ?

Comment: This is confusing `$image_type=IMAGETYPE_JPEG`

Comment: @HamZaDzCyberDeV Why is having a default value confusing?

Comment: @tlenss obviously since he isn't setting that value to PNG ?

Comment: It's not confusing, It's just unclear in his code.. good catch!

Comment: Because I have more if statements there, but I removed them to make it easier to read, you can see the original on the weblink

Comment: I'm not really into "debug" this script for me from "this link". This type of questions usually get closed, and some answers even get downvoted.

Comment: I'm trying to solve the problem that the png is saved with black background. I tried different methods to solve it which is not working. It's not that I haven't tried anything...

Comment: Ok try `$image->save($target, IMAGETYPE_PNG);`

Comment: does the image display correctly in the browser? to check add a header and remove the second parameter from imagepng

Answer (score 1):

You should probably change

```
$black = imagecolorallocate($im, 0, 0, 0);
```

to

```
$black = imagecolorallocate($image, 0, 0, 0);
```

Try setting image alpha blending

```
imagealphablending($image, false);
imagesavealpha($image, true);
```

Comment: eddited, does not change the result tough

Comment: Same, I have added those 2 lines before the colorallocate and after. No result

Comment: Then maybe take HamZa's advice and add the switch. In that case your example code is pretty much broken though...